# Python: Trying to scraping a site for odds

Tags: python

I'm trying to scrape a website called **website** for odds. The teams and odds are written in JavaScript which is why I use selenium's webdriver. I'm currently stuck.

From the code below I need to extract the teams and odds only, but if I use soup's find_all(), I cannot use get_text(), and if I use find(), I *can* use get_text(), but I only get the first team's name, then it stops - which it should, but how do I make it iterate to find all the teams? And after this find the odds?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.website.com"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

containers01 = soup.find("span", {"class": "c-events__team"})
print(containers01.get_text())
```

I am then trying to also find the odds and then extract it. I wanted to ask you guys in what format you would advice me to extract the data to in order to compare the odds with other bookmakers. SQL? json? csv?

Thank you so much in advance for reading this.

Comment: Why don't you loop over the list of results?

Comment: For the first issue, use `soup.findAll` and loop over the containers to get the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to collect the teams and odds for each row with this code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://1xbet.cm/en/live/Football/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

containers = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "c-events__item_col"})
for container in containers:
    teams = [x.get_text() for x in container.findAll(
        "span", {"class": "c-events__team"}
    )]
    odds = [x.attrs.get('data-coef') for x in container.findAll(
        "a", {"class": "c-bets__bet"}
    )]
    print(teams)
    print(odds)
    print()
```